# jQuery droppable and draggable count if correct

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I am new to jQuery and currently blocked at (I suppose) a simple issue.

I have two lists: a droppable and a draggable; 2 questions about that:

1) How to know the items that are dropped?
   So list all the items that are in the "dropped" zone.

2) How to check if the dropped items are in the correct drop zone?
   Each have an ID and should be dropped in the correct zone (drag1 to drop1).

Doing this "live" is easy, just check if ID of UI is the same as the ID of the $(this) with the drop-function.

But I want to allow the drop always and recalculate each time how many are dropped correctly.
   You can use a counter but the remove option (see example) will make that too complicate.

In short, how to iterate the droppables and check if the dropped one on it, is correct.

CODE : http://jsfiddle.net/setki/BCnyU/

Comment: Well, you've got invalid HTML: outside of HTML5 an `id` cannot start with a number. And you can't have duplicate `id`s, an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document.

Comment: oops, sorry about the html. Just did a little too much copy/past.
Corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a solution, although I am not too happy with it because it looks "strange".

What I do is add an extra Class to the Droppable: "OK".
It's a class that has no style (but can be used for styling if wanted).

```
if (dragID == dropID) {
  $(this).addClass('OK');
} else {
  $(this).addClass('NOK');
}
```

Then I just count all those who have that style

```
var numItems = $('.OK').length;
$('.counter').html('Correct: '+numItems +'/5');
```

And not to forget, remove the class also if draggable is removed from droppable

```
$(this).removeClass('OK NOK');
```

Well, anyone can use this simple solution, but I am keen to know if there really are no other solutions in jQuery.

The working example can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/setki/BCnyU/

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

add a start function to your draggable object, for example:

```
$('#yourelement').draggable({ revert: true, start: function() { $(this).addClass('active'); }
```

Now the element you're currenty dragging gets the class "active". Now in the drop function of your droppable you can check the id of this element like this:

```
var dragID = $('.active').attr('id');
```

To compare this to the id of the dropzone, you would need to get the drop id into a var aswell.

```
var dropID = $(this).attr('id');
```

and from here you will need to split the strings since its only the number you want to compare. Not sure how the split function works, just google "javascript .split", you should get an array, if you split for each symbol "drop1" for example would become an array containing 5 symbols, where the last one [4] would be the number. From here you can just compare these two splitted variables to each other. ie;

```
 if(splitted_dragID[4] == splitted_dropID[4]) {
       counter++;
       $('#counter').text('Correct: '+counter);
 }
```

This assuming you have an variabel named counter that adds one to itself each time the function is correct.

Hope this points you in the right direction! :)

Comment: Just a note, with this solution you are going to want to remove the ".active" class once the item has been dropped.
$('.active').removeClass('active').
Other than that +1 on the answer

Comment: i added the above code. I can iterate the ID of the droppable but how to get the variables "dragID" ? 
http://jsfiddle.net/setki/BCnyU/

Comment: The above code is not correct. When using that code, it goes wrong on the first "drop" because the class isn't found. Even more... there is no need to add a class because you can just get the ID directly like this : ui.draggable.attr('id')

Comment: My code wasn't handmade to work for what he was doing, so the classes in questions wasn't in the code. And yes, you're correct that ui.draggable.attr('id') might be a better solution, I'm not really that well known with the jqueryui api.